# ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Permission denied

Tags: ssh, permission-denied, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

ssh recently stopped working on my Ubuntu install.
The only change that I can think of that took place was a Windows update, however since then I have freshly installed Ubuntu several times to no avail.
Interestingly I am still able to connect to the remote server via ssh using Putty.

Below is the verbose debugging stream from the console:

```
user@PC:~$ ssh -vvv user@example.com 
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017 
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config 
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * 
debug2: resolving "example.com" port 22 
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0 
debug1: Connecting to example.com [111.11.11.11] port 22. 
debug1: connect to address 111.11.11.11 port 22: Permission denied 
debug1: Connecting to example.com [111.11.11.21] port 22. 
debug1: connect to address 111.11.11.21 port 22: Permission denied 
ssh: connect to host example.com port 22: Permission denied
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I have not been able to find any other threads that have this issue.

Comment: I Googled ssh "permission denied" and here are my top results and luckily from Stack Overflow sister websites:
https://superuser.com/questions/543626/ssh-permission-denied-on-correct-password-authentication
https://askubuntu.com/questions/315377/ssh-error-permission-denied-please-try-again

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have actually seen both of these already but in my issue I don't even get as far as connection established (debug1 line 4 on both threads). Both of those threads encounter authentication errors once the connection has been established. However, I can't even get to the stage where I can authenticate.

Comment: Check if Windows Firewall is blocking that connection. Also configure `ssh_config` file properly according to that website policy.

Answer (score 1):

Biswapriyo was correct!

After resetting my firewall settings to default (I had never set up any custom rules so this was a non-issue), I was able establish ssh connections once more.

Comment: Great to see that you were able to fix your problem! Answering your own question is allowed on SO (see [https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)). However your answer should be of the same quality as an answer from another person. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how you can improve your answer.